# Callable interface Loop stoping main method to execute further

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, httpclient, callable

I am trying to send request to server in every 2 seconds in a thread and check if there is something for me give it back to me....For getting value i have to use callable. I am not able to figure out how to run callable thread in every 2 seconds and get value back from it...here is my sample code of callable implementation...

```
public String call(){
    boolean done = true;
    String returnData = "";
    while(done){
        try {
            returnData = post.getAvailableChat();
            if(!returnData.equals("")){
                System.out.println("Value return by server is "+returnData);
                return returnData;
            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            done = false;
            Logger.getLogger(GetChatThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Now here is my main class code i know i did it wrong here in main class because my code will not go to next line after while loop....but please tell me how to do it

```
Callable<String> callable = new CallableImpl(2);                  

    ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);   
    System.err.println("before future executor");                    
    Future<String> future;                                           

    try {                                                           
        while(chatLoop_veriable){                                    
            future = executor.submit(callable);                         
            String serverReply = future.get();                      
            if( serverReply != null){                               
                System.out.println("value returned by the server is "+serverReply);
                Thread.sleep(2*1000);                               
            }//End of if                                            
        }//End of loop                                              
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rightly picked a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor but you don't take advantage of the methods it provides, in particular in your case: [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) instead of submit. You can then remove the sleep part as the executor will handle the scheduling for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Future.get()` is blocking  so control will not returned to you after that until thread completes. you should use [Future.get(long timeout,TimeUnit unit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

```
future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be more like this from the API docs
(note there is no "public" modifier so it probably needs to be a nested subclass or some alike to solve the access level of the variable)
it should be something like.....

```
Callable<String> call(){
 // code for the 2000 millisecond thread Callable is some sort of data/process for 
 // a thread to "do"
 return (Callable<String>)callable; // or 1
}
```

However , **java.util.concurrent.Executors** appears to be how this is achieved with Callable
note V is a vector as in the API docs.

Comment: V is a vector? Why the cast to Callable?